# Transformers(Pytorch) how to resume train when out of memory?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using BertModel for training in Transformers. I want to change `max_length` in mini-batch training. but this leads to OOM(Out of memory). The reason is that the constant tensor created in BertModel is not being recycled. I can use `gc.collect()` and `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` to force recovery, but this slows down training. How can I predict that OOM might occur and call `gc.collect()` and `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` appropriately?
The core code is as follows.

```py
def truncate_inputs(
        self,
        input_ids: torch.Tensor,
        attention_mask: torch.Tensor,
        token_type_ids: torch.Tensor,
        labels: torch.Tensor,
        max_length: int,
    ):
        input_ids = input_ids[:, :max_length].contiguous()
        attention_mask = attention_mask[:, :max_length].contiguous()
        token_type_ids = token_type_ids[:, :max_length].contiguous()
        labels = labels[:, :max_length].contiguous()
        return input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, labels
```

recycle:

```py
class GCCallBack(TrainerCallback):
    def on_step_end(
        self,
        args: NERTrainingArguments,
        state: TrainerState,
        control: TrainerControl,
        **kwargs,
    ):            
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

If I don't clear the cache. The speed is 10it/s (out of memory). If I follow the code, the speed is 3it/s~5it/s (max length is dynamic).
Baseline is 2it/s (max length is constant)